# set.clear() calls destructors of contained elements before removing the element

Tags: c++, stl, g++, libstdc++

In the following code I'd expect the assertion to pass, but it does not.

This is different from the [documented behavior of unique_ptr::reset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) and I find it quite surprising.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug? This is a problem because if the same element is removed a gain, the destructor is called twice.

```
#include <set>
#include <memory>

struct F
    : std::enable_shared_from_this<F>
{
    static int destructor_count;
    static std::set<std::shared_ptr<F>> container;

    F() {}

    ~F() {
        assert(container.size() == 0);
        container.clear(); // This will delete the same pointer twice.
        destructor_count--;
    }
};

int F::destructor_count = 0;
std::set<std::shared_ptr<F>> F::container;

int main()
{
    F::container.insert(std::shared_ptr<F>(new F));
    F::container.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler Information:

libstdc++6-4.6-dev

```
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Side note: use `std::make_shared`.

Comment: @chris to save on the verbosity?

Comment: There's that, but there's also exception safety sometimes. For example, if `f` takes two of them, `f(new A(), new B())` can cause a leak.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a reason `unique_ptr` is explicitly documented to behave that way: it's a stronger guarantee than you usually get for the rest of the standard library. If the same rule applied to all types then it wouldn't need to be stated specifically for `unique_ptr`.

Your code recursively calls `F::container.clear()` while another call to `F::container.clear()` is running. That is not guaranteed to work:

> **17.6.5.8  Reentrancy  [reentrancy]**
>    Except where explicitly specified in this standard, it is implementation-defined which functions in the Standard C ++ library may be recursively reentered.

Now unfortunately libstdc++ fails to document which functions can be recursively reentered, so it is safer to assume that none can be, so your assertion is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor of F is called while clearing the container, during which the container is not empty, thus the assertion failed.

Comment: Yes, But if I iterate the container from the within the destructor, a pointer to a partially destructed object is returned. This is different from the behavior of unique_ptr.

Comment: No, but calling reset() on unique_ptr sets the value to false before destroying the object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would expect that assertion to be true. You are not expected to know the details of how containers hold and destroy memory. You should not make assumptions about what happens during `std::set::clear()`, only trust that after it finishes all the destructors will be called and `std::set::size()` will return 0.

In this old Dr. Dobbs article [STL's Red-Black Trees](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/stls-red-black-trees/184410531), the backing data structure behind `std::set` is described. Nodes will get deleted (and their contents destructed) before the whole tree is empty, but rest assured by the end of `std::set::clear()` all the destructors will be called and `std::set::size()` will return 0.

Note: other implementations of `std::set` might used different backing data structures, red-black trees are only a possible implementation.

Comment: I dont see how elements are stored affects when the destructor is called. It would be straight forward to remove references to the contained element before destroying them.

Comment: What I mean is that it should be staright forward to remove the references to the node from the tree and then delete the node, rather than the other way round.

Comment: @nishantjr The implementation conforms to the standard and is performing in a way that is in line with that specification. If you have additional requirements beyond the standard, you will need to find an implementation which conforms to those additional requirements or build your own.

Comment: Removing references to nodes before destroying them would take more code and slow down everyone else's programs just to support your weird use case. It's possible to support that, but implementations can choose not to (see my answer) if they prefer to make `clear()` faster for the much more common use case.